# Eigenvalues of quadratic Casimirs of simple Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, invariants

I want to find a generic formula for calculating eigenvalue of quadratic casimirs of Lie groups, in terms of Dynkin labels.

For a simple example if we take $SU(2)$, with $[R]$ indicating the highest weight of the $(R+1)$-dim representation, I would get $(R/2)(R/2+1)$.

Is there a formula for other series of classical Lie algebras as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Up to normalization one finds, for $\hat e_k$ in a Hermitian basis of the algebra,
$$
\hat C_2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\ell \hat e_k^2 
$$
with eigenvalue 
$$
c_2=2\langle \Lambda\vert \delta\rangle +\langle \Lambda\vert\Lambda\rangle
$$
where $\vert\Lambda\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i\vert w_i\rangle$ is the highest weight state expressed in terms of the fundamental weights $\{\vert w_i\rangle\}$ and $\delta$ is the Weyl root, which is half of the sum of all positive roots.

The details on the derivation of this result can be found in

> J. F. Cornwell, Group Theory in Physics (Academic, New York,
>   1984), Vol. 2.

and worked out examples can be found in

> R. Slansky, Phys. Rep. 79, 1 (1981)

or

> Iachello, F., 2006. Lie algebras and applications (Vol. 12). Berlin:
>   Springer

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For any simple Lie algebra, if $\lambda$ is the highest weight in a representation and $\rho$ is the Weyl vector (the sum of fundamental weights or 1/2 the sum of the positive roots) then the Casimir is given by $Q= (\lambda, \lambda+2\rho)$. Here the inner product is the standard one on the weight space.

I regard  Chapter 13 in Di Francesco, Mathieu and Senenschal's "Conformal Field theory"  to be the best refernce on Lie algebra stuff for physicists. It's a completely self-contained acount of nearly everything one needs to know. You don't need to know an Conformal Field theory to read that chapter. It has a clear proof of this result.